# How to rename a file with a known name to a new name which is stored in a variable?

Tags: linux, bash

### [UPDATE-1]: **If possible, give me cons for motivation to learn the simplest commands.**

---

So, I have one file in directory:

```
ls | grep *.mp4
```

> video.mp4

I use this command to randomly rename & move file in another directory:

```
for a in *.mp4; do mv -n "$a" "${a/*/$RANDOM.mp4}"; done;  mv *.mp4 /home/misdeed/Documents
```

Is ok, I get randomly name for video.mp4

```
cd Documents; ls | grep *.mp4
```

> 19889.mp4

**Qestion**:

How to use is:

```
a="This is name file"
echo $a
```

> This is name file

for rename *.mp4 (not randomly) and for get

> This is name file.mp4

---

I need something like it:

- `a="This is name file"`
- `COMMAND FOR RENAME BUT WITHOUT $RANDOM. I WANT USE $a in renamed file`

Comment: `mv something.mp4 "$a".mp4`? Is the problem you don't know in advance what `something` is? In that case what if there are two files matching `*.mp4`? Is the premise there's always exactly one such file?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski only one file video.mp4: How I get it: ``ttyrec`` -> `ttyrec2gif` -> `ffmpeg -i tty.gif -movflags faststart -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" video.mp4`

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, upps, I try you solve! It helps: `mv *.mp4 "$a".mp4; mv *.mp4 /home/misdeed/Documents; cd Documents; ls | grep *.mp4`. Thank you very much!

Comment: So the name is always `video.mp4`, right? Then `mv video.mp4 "$a".mp4`. I'm confused and maybe not getting this right. You started with relatively complex code that involves random names and iterating over files, but in the end the question is "how to rename a file with a known name to a new name which is stored in a variable?" So basic `mv` and shell variable usage. If the variable is available when `ffmpeg` runs, you can pass `"$a".mp4` instead of `video.mp4` in the first place.

Comment: And please drop this `*.mp4`! It only works because you have just one matching file. Frankly `ls | grep *.mp4` is *very* wrong but it only affects what you see. If you ask a new question "what is wrong with `ls | grep *.mp4`?" you *will* learn a lot.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, yes, I know, i can just type `ls *.mp4`. I understand you, u very help me. Just I noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the original name is known in advance and it's `video.mp4`. You rename it with

```
mv video.mp4 "$a".mp4
```

Notes:

- If the variable is empty (or unset), the final name will be `.mp4`. Names starting with dot (`.`) are "hidden", plain `ls` skips them, you need `ls -a` to see them.
- If there is already a file with the target name, it will be lost and the former `video.mp4` file will take its name. To prevent mishaps consider `mv -i`; it will prompt for confirmation if the destination path exists.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the new random file name printed? In that case, the easiest is to reuse the value of your random variable.

```
for file in *.mp4; do
  RANDOM_NAME="${file/*/$RANDOM.mp4}";
  mv -n "$file" /home/misdeed/Documents/"$RANDOM_NAME";
  echo "This is name $RANDOM_NAME.mp4";
done
```

Comment: No, no. I want use assigned value of bash var for rename file. Ok?